# When is quis used instead of aliquis?

Tags: pronouns, conjunction

I definitely remember that one usually says: *si quis veniret …* and not: *si aliquis veniret*. But the [recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14349) about *quo quisque est sollertior* and similar forms brought the following rule from Allen & Greenough to my attention:

> The indefinite quis is rare except in the combinations sī quis (if any), nisi quis (if any . . . not), nē quis (lest any, in order that none), num quis (ecquis whether any) and in relative clauses.

([§ 310 no. 2](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indefinite-pronouns))

*Si, nisi, ne, num* are certainly uncontroversial, but I seem to remember that there was a longer list, so I looked it up in my pocket grammar (*Langenscheidts Kurzgrammatik Latein*, if you must know), and indeed it lists the following words calling for the *ali*-less pronoun: *si, nisi, ne, num, quo, quanto, cum*. And google-ing further, I also found other lists, such as: *si, nisi, ne, num, quo, ubi, quando, cum*.

And indeed I find, for example, this from Cicero ([Pro Rabirio postumo 36](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/rabiriopost.shtml#36)):

> Ubi semel quis peieraverit, ei credi postea, etiam si per pluris deos iuret, non oportet.
> *Once somebody has sworn falsely, one must not believe him any more, even if he should swear by multiple gods.*

It is generally understood that in all cases where you can say *quis* (or *quid*), you can generally also say *aliquis* (or *aliquid*) for emphasis. But where is it permissible (and needed, unless one wants to express emphasis) to leave out the *ali-* prefix?

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally permissible to substitute *quis* for *aliquis*, because *quis* functions as an interrogative when it's not bound in a subordinate clause that makes that meaning impossible.  *Aliquis venit* means "someone is coming".  *Quis venit* means "who is coming?"

*Quis venit?*  *Aliquis venit.* is a conversation, if a frustrating one.

*Quis venit?* *QUIS venit* is the start of a bad comedy sketch...much inferior to *Quis in primo?*

Not only can you not use *quis* as an indefinite in a main clause, you also can't in a subordinate clause that could be an indirect question.

Note also that *si aliquis* is not the only alternative to *si quis*.  *Quicumque* ("whosoever"), alternatively *quicunque*, also works if the same indefinite person will be the subject of the main clause verb also.  So sentences ending in *anathema sit* might start with any of *si quis*, *si aliquis*, *quicumque*, *quicunque*.

[*Magna Carta*](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/magnacarta.html) uses all of *si quis*, *si aliquis*, and *quicumque*.  Interestingly, at first glance it seems to prefer *aliquis* not for emphasis, but when an adjective is needed, as *Si aliquis liber homo*.

Getting back to the original question, if you are a native English speaker, the traditional translations of indefinite *quis* as "anyone" and *aliquis* as "someone" should be helpful to keep in mind, though not always to be taken literally in places where you could use either form in Latin.  Certainly I would not translate *si aliquis liber homo* as "if some free man" but as "if any free man".

Comment: That's all very well for *si*, but as I wrote, it's pretty uncontroversial that you can say *si quis…* But can I say: *Furtum fit, cum quis rem alienam amovet*? Or can I say: *Quo quis est doctior, eo est modestior*? What's up with these? Are they rare, non-classical, late Latin, neo-Latin, bad Latin?

Comment: I also gave a set of circumstances in which you can't use *quis* instead of *aliquis*.  You had seemed uncertain from the question what those circumstances might be.  If I knew more, I'd have said more.