# How would you say "The older a rabbit gets, the more it behaves like a dog."?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

How would you say "*The older a rabbit gets, the more it behaves like a dog.*" in Latin? The literal translation from English would be "*Senior cuniculus sit, plus agit ut canis.*", but I guess that's not proper Latin. In Croatian, you say "*Što je zec stariji, to se više ponaša kao pas.*", which would literally translate as "*Quod est cuniculus senior, id is plus agit ut canis.*", but I guess that's not proper Latin either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"The ... the ..." is *quo ... eo, hoc* or *tanto* (see also [this older answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14349/the-function-of-quo-in-qu%C5%8D-quisque-est-sollertior-h%C5%8Dc-docet-%C4%ABr%C4%81cundius/14350#14350)). Thus we can say:

> Quo quique cuniculus est senior, eo magis in modum canis se agit.

I think *plus* can also be used adverbially, but *magis* is more common. "Behave" in this sense is better captured by reflexive *se agere* than simple *agere*. Also, *ut canis* is not exactly wrong either, but *in modum canis* (in the manner of a dog) seems more descriptive to me.

Comment: Are *in modum* and *in modo* both valid? If yes, is there a difference?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Smith & Hall explicitly [warn](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh15620) against *in modo*, but simple *modo* would be fine, and apparently more or less interchangeable. (I guess similar to how "in the fashion of/after the fashion of" in English basically means the same.)

Comment: And, what do you think, is the sentence telling the truth?

Comment: @FlatAssembler I doubt it :)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I also think that rabbits don't actually love their owners.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Could, "The more democracies are threatened, the more they behave like tyrannies.", be translated analogously e.g. "quo quique liber-populus impendetur, eo magis in modum tyrannidis se agit."?

Comment: @tony That sounds good to me, only *liber populus* (a free people) is perhaps not the most obvious translation for "democracy." But then, there probably isn't a very good one. Georges gives the rather cumbersome *civitas populari imperio utens*.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thanks. One thing disturbs me: all the examples, here, and in your older answer, all have a comparative in both clauses. I omitted a "magis" in the "quo"-clause (Cicero had a comparative in the "quo"-clause); now, I'm not so sure--please advise. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Oxford gives a shorter, "civitas popularis", as well as "liber populus". I don't think that the Romans appreciated democracy, in the sense that we do; if they did, they weren't interested. The Romans didn't even bother to adopt the Greek word for it.

Comment: @tony Oops, you're right, there should be some comparative in your first part. Say, *quo quaeque civitas est infestior, eo …*